# MS VS formatstring specify used parameter with $

Tags: c, visual-studio, format-string

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to create a C program.

I want to test the formatstring parameters.

The only thing I'm trying to do is the following

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Test: %2$s\n","asdf","2asdf");
    return 0;
}
```

If i say `Test: %s` it uses the first parameter. But I want it to use the second parameter.
But my output here is `Test: $s`

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way to specify the second parameter to be used?

Comment: Just give the second if you only need the second.

Comment: This is a test. Later i need to give more. It's for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format specifier like `%2$s` in `printf` to specify the second parameter is not part of standard C, but a [POSIX extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). Visual Studio doesn't support it.